# Keeping a running list with a specific limit

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following sample dataset.

```
DECLARE _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS INT64 DEFAULT 2;

WITH `activity` AS (
    SELECT "2022-01-01" AS `date_time`, "tim" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-02" AS `date_time`, "sarah" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-04" AS `date_time`, "tim" AS `username`,  "extended" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-05" AS `date_time`, "ed" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-06" AS `date_time`, "ed" AS `username`,  "extended" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-07" AS `date_time`, "tim" AS `username`,  "canceled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-07" AS `date_time`, "tim" AS `username`,  "canceled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-08" AS `date_time`, "ed" AS `username`,  "canceled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-09" AS `date_time`, "lisa" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-10" AS `date_time`, "sarah" AS `username`,  "canceled" AS `activity`
)
```

I would like to analyze this dataset based on a specific limit to the number of enrollments. So have an overview of which enrollments would have been invalid if the limit was lower than the number of people applying.

The thing that I'm struggling with in this challenge is that, on every row, you need to keep a running list of `active_enrollments` that contains the usernames. You need to keep this list to know which "canceled" events you should process and which ones you can ignore. That's how I'm trying to solve the challenge, but maybe there is an entirely different way.

This is the outcome that I'm looking for.

```
-- _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS = 1
| date_time  | username | activity | valid_enrollment |
|------------|----------|----------|------------------|
| 2022-01-01 | tim      | enrolled | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | sarah    | enrolled | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | tim      | extended | 1 |
| 2022-01-05 | ed       | enrolled | 0 |
| 2022-01-06 | ed       | extended | 0 |
| 2022-01-07 | tim      | canceled | 1 |
| 2022-01-07 | tim      | canceled | 1 |
| 2022-01-08 | ed       | canceled | 0 |
| 2022-01-09 | lisa     | enrolled | 1 |
| 2022-01-10 | sarah    | canceled | 0 |
```

```
-- _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS = 2
| date_time  | username | activity | valid_enrollment |
|------------|----------|----------|------------------|
| 2022-01-01 | tim      | enrolled | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | sarah    | enrolled | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | tim      | extended | 1 |
| 2022-01-05 | ed       | enrolled | 0 |
| 2022-01-06 | ed       | extended | 0 |
| 2022-01-07 | tim      | canceled | 1 |
| 2022-01-07 | tim      | canceled | 1 |
| 2022-01-08 | ed       | canceled | 0 |
| 2022-01-09 | lisa     | enrolled | 1 |
| 2022-01-10 | sarah    | canceled | 1 |
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I hope that below give you some direction to your problem.

```sql
DECLARE _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS INT64 DEFAULT 2;

WITH RECURSIVE `activity` AS (
  -- put your sample data here
),
activities AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_time) AS rn, * FROM activity
),
enrollments AS (
  SELECT *,
         IF (_MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS > 0 AND activity = 'enrolled', [username], []) AS enrolled_users,
         IF (_MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS = 0 AND activity = 'enrolled', 0, 1) AS valid_enrollment
    FROM activities WHERE rn = 1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT e.rn + 1, a.date_time, a.username, a.activity,
         CASE
           WHEN a.activity = 'enrolled' AND ARRAY_LENGTH(enrolled_users) < _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS THEN e.enrolled_users || [a.username]
           WHEN a.activity = 'canceled' THEN ARRAY(SELECT u FROM UNNEST(e.enrolled_users) u WHERE u <> a.username)
           ELSE e.enrolled_users
         END AS enrolled_users,
         CASE
           WHEN a.activity = 'enrolled' AND ARRAY_LENGTH(enrolled_users) = _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS THEN 0
           WHEN a.activity IN ('extended', 'canceled') AND a.username NOT IN UNNEST(enrolled_users) THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END AS valid_enrollment
    FROM enrollments e JOIN activities a ON e.rn + 1 = a.rn
)
SELECT date_time, username, activity, valid_enrollment FROM enrollments
 ORDER BY rn;
```

**Query results**

[image]

***Outdated answer***

It will return *enrolled usernames* limited to the number of `_MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS` at a given `datetime`, (though `valid_enrollment` column in your outcome is not clear to me).

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT (enrollments),
       ARRAY (
         SELECT username FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT username,
                  LAST_VALUE(IF(activity = 'enrolled', date_time, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w1 AS last_enrolled
             FROM UNNEST(enrollments)
          QUALIFY LAST_VALUE(activity) OVER w1  <> 'canceled'
           WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY date_time 
                              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
         ) ORDER BY last_enrolled LIMIT 2 --<-- _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS
       ) AS valid_enrollment
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(username, t.activity, date_time)) OVER w0 AS enrollments
      FROM `activity` t
    WINDOW w0 AS (ORDER BY date_time)
  );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot of the pointer @Jaytiger but I probably didn't explain my initial example well enough. As you write in `row 6` `sarah` becomes listed as enrolled but that shouldn't be the case. The thing that I didn't make clear is that enrollment don't go into a `pending` state. If they miss a window, they are just dropped and not queued.

As for the `valid_enrollment` column, the idea is that every row that is part of a valid enrollment would be set to `1` so that in the next step, I can extract just the rows that are part of a valid enrollment.

Comment: @mrdwd, thanks for the explanation, I've updated the answer again based on my understanding.

Comment: Your update answer works like a charm! I'm just trying to grapple with what's actually going on in this query :) Also any thoughts on the performance of this query? As in would the major speed limiting factor be the size of `_MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS` or rather the total number of rows?

Comment: I noticed that I overlooked.one thing in my sample data. For every `extended` event an additional `cancellled` event is added to the log (don't ask). So that means that `tim` would have two `cancelled` events on `2022-01-07. Right now only the first event is marked as valid. I can probably merge those events in a follow-up step but maybe you have a idea how that could be done in your query. (I've updated the sample data in the opening post).

Comment: *RECURSIVE CTE* is Pre-GA and has some contraints of not being scalable, so this solution will be limited by *the total number of rows*, I think.

Comment: And to solve your updated sample, one possible approach is to keep number of enrollment or extension in the *struct* variable like `[STRUCT(username, 1 AS cnt)], []) AS enrolled_users` and used it as a stack. But unfortunately, this will return *Struct type is not supported in the WITH RECURSIVE output error* due to another limitation of current *recursive CTE* . I hope this limitation be resolved on GA(Generally Available) stage. Anyway until then, I think you can preprocess it as you mentioned.

Comment: I solved the final challenge using a simple follow-up query that selects all the `canceled` activities that belong to an already validated canceled trade and then just UNION ALL both tables. Thanks so much for your help! The recursive CTE is something entirely new for me. Now curious to see how it will perform in a real-world scenario :)

Comment: On my real dataset I'm running into this error `Query error: A recursive CTE has reached the maximum number of iterations: 100.` So would the hard limit of this query be 100 rows in the dataset?

Comment: yes, it's current limitation of recursive CTE.  see below 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#recursive_cte  *If recursion does not terminate, the query fails after reaching 100 iterations.*

Comment: So with the way the current query is set up, is 100 rows the limit? I'm not sure how an iteration is calculated here. But I guess the path of recursive CTEs turns out to be a dead end as I have a dataset of thousands of records :(

Answer (score 0):

There is the need to generate an array as a list with all enroll people. In the next steps the "canceled" people are removed from that array.

```sql
DECLARE _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS INT64 DEFAULT 2;

WITH activity AS (
 # SELECT "2021-01-05" AS `date_time`, "ed" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-01" AS `date_time`, "tim" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS activity UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-02" AS `date_time`, "sarah" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-04" AS `date_time`, "tim" AS `username`,  "extended" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-05" AS `date_time`, "ed" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-06" AS `date_time`, "ed" AS `username`,  "extended" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-07" AS `date_time`, "tim" AS `username`,  "canceled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-08" AS `date_time`, "ed" AS `username`,  "canceled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-09" AS `date_time`, "lisa" AS `username`,  "enrolled" AS `activity` UNION ALL
    SELECT "2022-01-10" AS `date_time`, "sarah" AS `username`,  "canceled" AS `activity`
),

help as (select *,
if(activity.activity="enrolled",1,0) as enroll,
if(activity.activity="canceled",1,0) as cancel,
 from activity ),

 help1 as (select *,
 array_agg(if(enroll=1,username,"NULL")) over win as arr1
 from help
 window win as (order by date_time range between unbounded preceding and current row)
 ),
 help2 as (select *, 
 (Select array_agg(x order by offset) from (select x,offset from unnest(arr1) x with offset where cancel!=1 or x!=username)) as arr2
  from help1) ,

 help3 as (select *, 
 (Select array_agg(x order by offset) from
 (Select x,offset from
  (select x,min(offset) offset from unnest(arr2) x with offset where x!="NULL" group by x)
  qualify row_number() over (order by offset)<= _MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS)
  ) as arr3
  from help2)
 
Select *,
array_length(arr3) as arr3_length,
array_length(arr3)-ifnull((array_length(lag(arr3) over (order by date_time))),0) as delta_enroll,
enroll-cancel as delta_enroll_expected

from
help3
order by date_time
```

The table `help` adds two new columns `enroll` and `cancel`, each set to one, if true.

The table `help1` generates an array `arr` of all enrolled people to that date. If in a row not an enroll happens, we add the string `"NULL"` and delete these in the further steps.

The table `help2` removes the people who canceled. This is done by a sub-select-query.

The `table3` removes the `"NULL"` dummy string and if there are people applying several times. Also the array is set to the maximum length `_MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS`.

Finally we check for the change of the enrollment list `delta_enroll`. If comparing this value with the `delta_enroll_expected` the enrollment/canceling can be check for successfulness.

Comment: First of all thanks! I'm running into two problems with this query. 

1. The `cancel` event on `row 6` from `tim` should still be part of `arr3`, now it's not.

2. When you set `_MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS` to `1` you'll see that on `row 6` `sarah` gets added to `arr3` but that shouldn't be the case. As she missed her initial enrollment on `row 2` all the other activities should be invalidated. So enrollments aren't queued if that makes sense.

Comment: A solution to problem 1 would be to only add a `username` to `arr1` if the array size is smaller than `_MAX_ACTIVE_ENROLLMENTS`. You'd need to get the array size in the previous row. Don't think that's possible on a running list.